# "總會" to mean "definitely", is this usage proper?

Tags: usage, lyrics

In the lyrics to [《寂寞寂寞就好》](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyFIzKYQQYE) there is a line which reads:

> 我總會把你戒掉

From context, I gather that “總會" means *definitely*, in other words:

> 我一定會把你戒掉

I have never seen this usage before, is this proper or just informal as used in song lyrics.

Comment: it's like 'anyway' or 'after all'.

Comment: Yes, you can think that way, as it is something you have decided to do. However, I think "終會" is more appropriate than "總會" if not for rhyming requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general content of the lyrics suggest the possible happening of a future event, which is "most likely" to happen, but not yet at the time of singing.

Thus words like "eventually", "finally -- 終會", "most likely" would seem appropriately within context.

As for "definitely", I would consider it an "outside possibility" given the context of the preceding words --  人本來就寂寞的 我總會把你戒掉, meaning "(since) people are originally / meant to be lonely, I would (therefore) "definitely" give you up"?

However, given that it is a future event, "definitely" is too definite, though not wrong per se. So, the other suggestions seem more in keeping with the general thrust of the lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 總會 is more like "eventually".

一定 seems more urgent compared 總會.

Comment: So in other words, “總會有一天我..."，right?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's valid, but obviously it depends on what context you want to use it in. You could also potentially split it into 我總有一天會...